# input/button with select-like chevron in HTML

Tags: html, button

Is there an `<input>` or `<button>` type that makes a `<select>`-like chevron? I tried `<input type="select"/>` with no success. Or is it possible to use `<select>` as an input/button? If none of these are possible/recommended, what is the simplest way to make a button with a chevron?

Comment: Please write your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The select tag is an input!

Here is an example of the select Tag

```
<select>
  <option value="optionOne">Option 1</option>
  <option value="optionTwo">Option 2</option>
  <option value="optionThree">Option 3</option>
  <option value="optionFour">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

To see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/y4hh3ued/